# Copy Cell on Worksheet_Change event if some criteria is met

Tags: vba, event-handling, excel

This code is working fine, but it looks awful (yes, I am a rookie on this thing). How can I improve it to look better?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Conditional Formatting
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If Target.Column > 6 And Target.Column < 8 And (Target.Value = "G" Or Target.Value = "Y" Or Target.Value = "R" Or Target.Value = "g" Or Target.Value = "y" Or Target.Value = "r") Then
Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy

Call ChangeG
End If

If Target.Column > 4 And Target.Column < 6 And (Target.Value = "High" Or Target.Value = "Medium" Or Target.Value = "Low" Or Target.Value = "high" Or Target.Value = "medium" Or Target.Value = "low") Then
Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy

Call ChangeE
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Depends on what `ChangeG` and `ChangeE` subs do for you...

Comment: It would be nice to see those subs too, but we can certainly review what's here.

Comment: @RubberDuck `Application.Proper(Target.Value) = "Whatev"` would clean up those redundancies right?

Answer (score 8):

- Indent everything one level inside of the `Sub...End Sub` block. Go one more inside of `If` blocks and loops.

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
      ' all code starts at this level of indentation

      If condition Then
          ' one more level 
      End If

  End Sub
  ```
- There shouldn't be more than one blank line between instructions.

  > ```
  > Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  >     'Conditional Formatting
  >     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  >
  >
  >     If Target.Column > 6 And Target.Column < 8 And (Target.Value = "G" Or Target.Value = "Y" Or Target.Value = "R" Or Target.Value = "g" Or Target.Value = "y" Or Target.Value = "r") Then
  >     Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy
  > ```
- This condition can be simplified.

  > ```
  > Target.Column > 6 And Target.Column < 8
  > ```

  means the same thing as `Target.Column = 7`. Same goes for

  > ```
  > Target.Column > 4 And Target.Column < 6
  > ```

  That can simply be `Target.Column = 5`.
- I don't normally advise using line continuations, but they can be justifiably used to reduce the amount of horizontal scrolling.

  ```
  If Target.Column = 7 And _
      (Target.Value = "G" _
          Or Target.Value = "Y" _
          Or Target.Value = "R" _
          Or Target.Value = "g" _
          Or Target.Value = "y" _
          Or Target.Value = "r") Then

      Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy

      Call ChangeG
  End If
  ```
- That last change brought to light the fact that you want to match on upper or lower case versions of these letters. Using VBA's [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator will help clean that up with some built in pattern matching.

  ```
  If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value Like "[GgYyRr]" Then

      Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy

      Call ChangeG
  End If
  ```

  Note that it cleans it up so well, that the line continuation isn't needed anymore.
- Don't use the `Call` keyword. It's unneeded and archaic. It's simply a leftover from an ancient version of VBA.
- The second condition is a little harder to clean up, but we can still use `Like` to make it better.

  ```
  If Target.Column = 5 And _
      (Target.Value Like "[Hh]igh" _
          Or Target.Value Like "[Mm]edium" _
          Or Target.Value Like "[Ll]ow") Then

      Sheets("Pending").Cells(1, 1).Copy
      ChangeE
  End If
  ```
- You've hard coded the string literal for the `"Pending"` sheet twice. It would be better to initialize a `Worksheet` variable upon entering the event routine.

  ```
  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Pending")
  ```

  Note that I used the `Worksheets` collection instead of `Sheets`. That's because the Sheets collection can contain charts as well as worksheets. It's a rare issue, but it can be one.

And there ya go. All cleaned up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Pending")

    If Target.Column = 7 And Target.Value Like "[GgYyRr]" Then
        sourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Copy
        ChangeG
    End If

    If Target.Column = 5 And _
        (Target.Value Like "[Hh]igh" _
            Or Target.Value Like "[Mm]edium" _
            Or Target.Value Like "[Ll]ow") Then

        sourceSheet.Cells(1, 1).Copy
        ChangeE
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

One last thing that I have not addressed, but was mentioned in the comments by [Tim Williams](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/63166/tim-williams). There is a potential bug waiting to rear its ugly little head. `Target` can be a multi-cell range object and `Range.Value` is not available in multi-cell ranges. You need to be prepared to deal with that situation should it arise. Consider the example below.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Set Workbook = ThisWorkbook

    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    'Set sheet = Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set sheet = Workbook.Worksheets(1)

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = sheet.Range("C2")

    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = sheet.Range("C2:C10")

    Debug.Print rng1.Value ' prints the value stored in C2
    Debug.Print rng2.Value ' raises type mismatch error #13

End Sub
```

Comment: One more thing to add to this excellent answer: it's important to remember that `Target` can be a multi-cell range (eg I can use Crtl-Enter to fill multiple cells in one operation).  So it's best to code this type of event with that in mind.

Comment: You're very right @TimWilliams. Good catch!