# Key on a Header and Offset

Tags: vba, excel

I have a section of code that I've been attempting to clean up and hopefully speed up. The section of code where I pass values in order to generate a key and update a table on a different sheet I think is my biggest problem. However I would like any suggestions/modifications to clean this section up first.

An overview is my worksheet has a header section where the user will update the monthly  sales,units or avg. cost field. Once this is done I need to recalculate all values in that month. This is anywhere from 10 to 1200 rows. As the update executes the following occurs:

1. Cell is updated with the impact of the header change.
2. A new unique key is built.
3. The new key is found in a table and the change value is inserted.

I was stuck manually changing the "ColumnCount" variable to maintain the offset in the proper position. Any help would be great.

```
'Table update afet net units header update
Dim i As Integer
'LastRow used to determine final used row on worksheet
    LastSourceRow = LastRow(destsheet, "B")
'Column Count initially set to -2 to offset target to desired cell
    ColumnCount = -2
    RowCount = 1

'Runs from row 1 to the last row on the sheet
For RowCount = 1 To LastSourceRow Step 5
    i = 5
    'After header change offset 5 rows and 2 columns back to capture cell change

    Set target = target.Offset(i, ColumnCount)

        'Running Status
        Application.StatusBar = "Target value change : " & target.Row & " of " & LastSourceRow & " " & Format(target.Row / LastSourceRow, "Percent")

            'If change cell is 0 then skip and sel column count to 0 to keep offset aligned
            If target = 0 Then

            'Do Nothing if 0 value
            ColumnCount = 0
            Else

                'Generate unique key and pass to table update module
                modTableUpdate.TableUpdate target, destsheet, sourcesheet, ColumnHeader, ColumnFormula, Celladdress, Key, cell, result

                'offset target by 1 to capture change
                ColumnCount = 1

                'Set target offset to new cell
                Set target = target.Offset(, ColumnCount)

                'Generate key and pass target offset value to table update module
                modTableUpdate.TableUpdate target, destsheet, sourcesheet, ColumnHeader, ColumnFormula, Celladdress, Key, cell, result

                'Set target offset back to original cell
                ColumnCount = -1

                Set target = target.Offset(, ColumnCount)
                'Set column count to 0 to maintain alignment when loop repeats

                ColumnCount = 0
            End If
Next RowCount
```

Comment: I strongly recommend editing the title to at least hint about what the code is doing - *not* what you want out of a review.

Comment: I took a stab at the title and made formatted your list as a list. Feel free to further improve the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing a little guess work here because you've not shown us the method'd signature. I apologize if I've made some bad assumptions.

Typically, when I see a `Target` Range, it means we're working inside of a worksheet's OnChange event. Assuming that, I would recommend introducing a new Range variable into the mix so you're not accidentally modifying the incoming range. Adding an extra variable would make it clear and explicit when/if you're programmatically changing the same range the user modified.

This snippet makes me believe it's the right thing to do even if my assumption is wrong.

> ```
>                 'Set target offset to new cell
>                 Set target = target.Offset(, ColumnCount)
>
>                 'Generate key and pass target offset value to table update module
>                 modTableUpdate.TableUpdate target, destsheet, sourcesheet, ColumnHeader, ColumnFormula, Celladdress, Key, cell, result
>
>                 'Set target offset back to original cell
>                 ColumnCount = -1
>
>                 Set target = target.Offset(, ColumnCount)
>                 'Set column count to 0 to maintain alignment when loop repeats
> ```

By introducing an `offsetTarget` variable, you should be able to avoid tracking the column count and all this setting and resetting because you've never modified `target` to begin with.

The other thing I would be careful of is detailed [at the end of this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/77737/41243) and again assumes this code resides in the `Worksheet_Change` event. `Target` could possibly be a multi-cell Range. Double check your code to make sure it can deal with that edge case.

One last thing. This method takes in an awful lot of parameters.

> ```
> modTableUpdate.TableUpdate target, destsheet, sourcesheet, ColumnHeader, ColumnFormula, Celladdress, Key, cell, result
> ```

Consider creating a simple class to encapsulate that data and simplify the call.

```
modTableUpdate.TableUpdate instanceOfYourAwesomeNewClass
```